# Yii calling controller function from another controller

Tags: php, forms, yii

In my web application the work flow demands that I should call one controller function from another function
Should I do add extra code or some configuration to proceed ? Right now This is how I implemented .But When I click "save" button nothing is happening values are just getting empty from the   form .

My code  .I want to create  an object of model "BookVegetable" inside "ProducerOfferController" . 
My code inside producerOffer controller

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    //$book_vegetable=new BookVegetable;
    $model=new BookVegetable;
    if(isset($_POST['BookVegetable']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['BookVegetable'];
        $model->booked_by = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $model->save();
        if ($model->hasErrors() === false)
        {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
    }
    $this->render('book',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

My code for from view

```
    <div style='padding-left:50px'>
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array('id'=>'non-ajax_form','enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>
    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <?php echo "<br>" ?>


    <?php echo CHtml::textField("booked_quantity",$model->booked_quantity); ?>
```

My scenario

```
public function actionBookvegetable($id){
    $BookVegetable=new BookVegetable;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['ProducerOffer'],$_POST['BookVegetable']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['ProducerOffer'];
        $BookVegetable->attributes=$_POST['BookVegetable'];
        $BookVegetable->booked_by=Yii::app()->user->id;
        $BookVegetable->producer_offer_id=$model->id;
        $model->save();
        $BookVegetable->save();

        if (($model->hasErrors() === false)||($BookVegetable->hasErrors()=== false))
        {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
          }
    }
        else
        {
            Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
        }
        $this->render('book',array('model'=>$model,'BookVegetable'=>$BookVegetable));
        }






<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=>  'Save',)); ?>
```

How should I resolve this ? Is it essential  to add anything extra to use one controller action inside another  controller
The url before saving and its the same after I press save also

```
 http://localhost/xxx/producerOffer/bookvegetable/20?returnUrl=%xxx%2FproducerOffer%2Fmanage
```

Comment: what do you want exactly to be done and tell me at which point of actionCreate you need to access another controller action and what is the code of the other controller action you refer. tnx

Comment: Inside "ProducerOffer" Controller I want to  use create action of "BookVegetable" controller .  My scenario is like I want to fetch data from two models   . For one model "ProducerOffer" its the existing record and for the "BookVegetable"  it is the create action . I will add the complete code

Comment: I have added my full code. The code for the "ProducerOffer" is working ,but when I use create action of "BookVegetable" controller, its not working ,when I click save its just becoming empty

Comment: Sorry still its hard to understand what you need to be done. do you refer "actionBookvegetable" to be not working or "actionCreate" ? also can you copy paste your whole code.. what you have copied is just two actions on a controller. copy past the whole controller code and if possible put a screenshot as what you need with URL's

Comment: I mean the action create of "BookVegetable"   when I use inside  "ProducerOffer" controller  , after I  click "save" it is just showing empty value in search box.

Comment: I mean the action "BookVegetable" is not working when I combine both models. For troubleshooting I tried to create  a record of "BookVegetable" inside "ProducerOffer" controller which is not working. I tried  to find  the area of trouble.

Comment: whats the error you get please?

Comment: After I type the values in the  text box of view form and click "save"  , its not saving and redirecting to the correct url , the value I entered inside text box of form is becoming null and remaining in the same page.

Comment: Whats the URL before you click save and whats the URL you go to after clicking save ?

Comment: The url does not change at all after clicking , it remains same

Comment: Ok but paste the current URL and where you expect it go after clicking save

Comment: My url when I am inside the form

Comment: Url is missing. please post both url in the question area. tx

Answer (score 0):

According to your information provided.. when you go here,

http://xxx.yyy.zzz/xxxx/producerOffer/create

Actually it should show you the form of book and when you click the save button there and go to `returnUrl`.

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

I suggest you to write the following as,

```
$model->save();
$BookVegetable->save();

if (($model->hasErrors() === false)||($BookVegetable->hasErrors()=== false))
{
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
  }
```

To

```
if($model->save() && $BookVegetable->save())
    $this->redirect('yourAction'); //if params needed, $this->redirect(array('yourAction', 'id' => $model->id));
```

When you go here, http://xxx.yyy.zzz/xxxx/producerOffer/bookvegetable

What ever the code you have written under ActionBookvegetable will trigger.

To make sure your values submitted properly please change this code

```
$model->save();
if ($model->hasErrors() === false)
{
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
}
```

To

```
if($model->save())
    $this->redirect('yourAction');
else
    print_r(getErrors());
```

This will print any errors thats preventing from saving the model. let me know after you try this.

Comment: Y  I tried its not showing the errors , its the same. Actually what I want is actionBookvegetable($id), actioncreate was just using for tracing the source of error .I edited the code but it is not making any difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in Yii2

**Background**

In SiteController action index method get the records of all objects from another model called voyzes.

**In SiteController**

Include the other model ex. Voyzes

[image]

Now in the SiteController action index method, implement the code to access the model/SQL/NoSQL or anything and set it in a array and return it to the view. For ex.

[image]

Now in the index view you should have your data from another model.

Answer (score -1):

In my work , I have a lot of logic around the "loadModel" routine in controllers to make sure the user logged in has access to the particular model.  I found this to work from another controller when I need to access the model, without moving or re-copying the loadmodel routine:

```
$caseviewController = Yii::app()->createController('Caseview');
//use this method from caseview controller to securley load case view model
$caseview = $caseviewController[0]->loadModel($caseviewid);
```